# Optimizing "Removing duplicates" thread state

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to hunt down MySQL variables/settings and metrics relevant to the "Removing duplicates" thread state.

Here's a snippet from `show full processlist`.

```
Id      User    Host    db      Command Time    State   Info    Rows_sent    Rows_examined   Rows_read
123456  user    123.123.132.123:12345      database        Query   12601   Removing duplicates     INSERT INTO table_a ... select distinct from table_b ... group by field_a, field_b, field_c ..     0       0       0
```

All but `Time` has been redacted from the aforementioned output. You can see that its been running for quite some time (12601 seconds). Usually, the query runs within minutes. However, ever so often, the application will come across a set of id's (from the select) that have a larger result set (>100,000).

The MySQL documentation says ...

- Removing duplicates

`The query was using SELECT DISTINCT in such a way that MySQL could not optimize away the distinct operation at an early stage. Because of this, MySQL requires an extra stage to remove all duplicated rows before sending the result to the client.`

My question is, what is this "extra stage" and what variables and/or metrics would be applicable for improving performance?

Comment: If you added the full query, you might get more help. A query with both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` has good chances of being rewritten.

Comment: Thanks ypercube but I've already rewritten the query to make it faster. I'm specifically interested in what the  "Removing duplicates" is doing.

Comment: It removes duplicate rows produced by the query (those that wouldn't be removed if you hadn't added the `DISTINCT`.)

Comment: No, that's not the optimized query.

Comment: I get that MySQL is removing duplicates. What I don't get, is what all is involved in that process. AKA, what variables or metrics to look at. The result sets are not that large (100,000-500,000). It's clearly not a simple operation and/or I'm hitting a limit somewhere.

Comment: If the intermediate state results in a lot of rows with no index, then MySQL would have to do a full table scan to remove duplicates, which would take a long time. I am having the same issue and I will need to see if adding an index to a table would help, or if I have to rewrite my query in some way.